# How can I mock an react hook using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a component which requests data. After a successful data fetching notification should be displayed. For this reason we have a package (in yarn workspaces) called like `@my-company/notifications`.

```
import { useNotification } from '@my-company/notifications';

const ComponentWithDataFetching = () => {
  const {
    enqueueInfoNotification,
  } = useNotification();
  const {
    data,
  } = useQuery({
    onCompleted: () => {
      enqueueInfoNotification({ message: 'Data successfully fetch' });
    },
  })
}
```

I would to test it

```
import { useNotification } from '@my-company/notifications';
import { render, fireEvent, act, wait } from '@testing-library/react';

jest.mock('@my-company/notifications', () => ({
  useNotification() {
    return {
      enqueueInfoNotification: jest.fn(),
    };
  },
}));

describe('<ComponentWithDataFetching />', () => {
  it('should enqueue info notification', async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <TestSuitWrapper>
        <ComponentWithDataFetching />
      </TestSuitWrapper>,
    );

    expect(useNotification).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

When tests run, an error occurs:
`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

If remove `jest.mock` test starts without errors. How can I mock an react hook for test call `enqueueInfoNotification` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is you can mock the `@mycompany/notifications` module, and in the test you can implement it to return a mock function called `enqueueInfoNotification` and test it whether it is called or not. But you should also mock useQuery which you can do it by using [apollo-react-tesing](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/) package

```js
import { useNotification } from '@mycompany/notifications';
import { render, fireEvent, act, wait } from '@testing-library/react';

jest.mock('@astral-frontend/notifications');

describe('<ComponentWithDataFetching />', () => {
  it('should enqueue info notification', async () => {
    useNotification.mockReturnValue({
       enqueueInfoNotification: jest.fn()
    });

    render(
      <TestSuitWrapper>
        <ComponentWithDataFetching />
      </TestSuitWrapper>,
    );

    expect(useNotification.enqueueInfoNotification).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank u, but now i get one more error `NotificationsProvider(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, ret
urn null.` Because from `@my-company/notifications` import `NotificationsProvider` and `jest.mock` probably override this.

Comment: Two simple actions for it works well:

1) `import NotificationsProvider from '@my-company/notifications/src/NotificationsProvider';`

2)  `expect(useNotification().enqueueInfoNotification.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);`

Comment: Yes if you add the provider and add some mock data as a prop to the provider then the error will be gone